# Add acf field variable to jquery

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I created field in Advanced custom fields:

```
<div class="field_class">
  <?php if( get_field('field') ): ?>
     <h4><?php the_field('field'); ?></h4>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

and I want to add acf field to jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.content-wrapper').addClass('field_class');

});
```

I know that I must add variable to jquery like:

```
var field = "<?php the_field('field'); ?>" ;
```

but don't know how this variable add to addClass: addClass('field_class') to grab all content (class and variable).

Thanks for help,

Answer (score 0):

First you need to store field value in a PHP variable

```
<?php 
   $fieldvar = get_field('field_name');
?>
```

Then add this variable as jQuery class

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.content-wrapper').addClass('<?php echo $fieldvar; ?>');
});
```

Comment: If I add $fieldvar = get_field('field_name');  to child functions I get: <div class="content-wrapper <?php echo $fieldvar; ?>">

Comment: I am not clear what do you need exactly, please explain.

Comment: I want to add acf field in content wth jquery (grab class with acf field), because I didn't figured out how can Insert acf field to print format from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51596867/add-php-to-html-print-formated-1s-2s-3s

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.content-wrapper').addClass(field);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right, but try to add echo as you are trying to add value in your script directly :

```
var field = "<?php echo the_field('field'); ?>" ;
```

or try

```
var field = "<?php echo get_field('field'); ?>" ;
```

the_field() work similar to echo get_field but you can give it a try.

Comment: Hello, I try to add `code`$field = "<?php echo get_field or the_field('field'); ?>" ;`code` to child functions and to template where i want to display field and I get error that variable is not defined. I try to add this field now as append in js`code`jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.class_before').append(field);
});`code`. Input filed is working in admin and on post but can display it on that template where I want to show field.

Comment: You are trying to add javascript with PHP that is not gonna work because javascript compiles at frontend DOM and PHP Code executes on server-side.

Comment: Thanks, but don't understand, php variable is declared in seperated - php template. What did I missed?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it does not have a proper answer, a solution.

So here is a workaround for you buddy.

1. create the ACF field.
2. Store the val

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old but here is the answer.
Create custom field `<?php the_field( 'primary_title', 'option' ); ?>`
Then you need to localize the js file. For example `js-localize.js`

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'js-localize', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/js-localize.js', array ( 'jquery' ), NULL, true);
wp_localize_script( 'js-localize', 'fieldsJS',
    array(
        'title' => get_field('primary_title', 'option'),
        )
);
```

And in `js-localize.js` file make a variable

```
let titleJs = fieldsJS.title;
```

you can easily test using the console with

```
console.log(titleJs);
```